# How can we generalize the fact of finite dimensional vector space to an infinte dimensional case?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am reading vector space from Friedberg. There in the last section they told about infinite dimensional vector space but there is not sufficient contents. Now my question is why can't we define infinite sum? If this is the case then can anyone please tell me the difference between infinite sum in the series in analysis and here? How infinite sum in series is defined and not here?

**I know I'm going wrong somewhere, please help me to find it out.**

Comment: Infinite sums in analysis are defined as limits of the sequence of *finite* partial sums. In general  there is no limit in vector spaces.

Comment: @Jens Schwaiger please elaborate, I cant understand about how can we define infinite sum by limit of a sequence? And also what are the bounds that we can't do in vector spaces?

Comment: @user639336 What you are asking is not at all related to the dimension of vector spaces.

Answer (score 7):

It's not that one can't define an infinite sum, the issue is that in a space with a binary operation an infinite sum does not automatically make sense. You can't define an infinite sum solely in terms of the finite sum. You need to construct the sequence of partial sums, which then needs to converge.

However, in order to define convergence, you need something like a topology, and we're no longer talking simply about vector spaces anymore: we've moved on to topological vector spaces. So one could arguably say that in a plain vector space, which explicitly isn't given a topology, you can't define an infinite sum.

Comment: sir you are saying topological vector spaces, are they define infinite as a limit of a sequence or anything else? But sir whenever it's about infinite sum of a series we write something lile a1e1+a2e2+........ doesn't it seems like ordinary binary operation? Secondly I read somewhere we can add if all elements are zero except finitely many. Please help sir about clearing my ideas.

Comment: sir somehow  are you want to mean topological vector spaces as functional analysis?

Comment: @user639 If all are zero but finitely many, that will converge in any topology so we don't need an explicit one. Just writing the infinite sum in general doesn't tell you which element of the vector space you're talking about. What if I wrote $1+1+1+\cdots$? This gives the sequence of partial sums $1,2,3,\ldots$, and this doesn't converge. Would you say that that was a silly example? We can't distinguish this from any other example without a topology. In fact you could define a topology where this actually does converge.

Comment: @user Topological vector spaces certainly do occur frequently in functional analysis, but they are also studied outside of that subject.

Comment: sir this means the only essence of topology is laid on infinite dimensional vector space? I mean in finite one the sum is defined, but in the infinite one the infinite sum is'nt.

Comment: sir but then with the help of a suitable topology does every infinite sequence converge? I read somewhere that in finite dimensional where we consider infinite sum (by defining norm or inner product ) may not be the element of the space(in the natural sense of vector spaces is'nt closed), is it means the infinite sequence is'nt convergence?

Comment: sir then the space R^∞ is closed(in the sense of finite vector spaces )? I mean the sequence (1,2,3,....... )is in R^∞, but not converges.

Comment: sir I know I've some problems to figure it out, if you please bear me to tell the things roughly it would be a huge help.

Comment: @user You can also define infinite sums for finite vector spaces, and the same problems arise for infinite ones as for finite ones. That sequence is not in $\mathbb R^\infty$ because all but finitely many need to be zero, but it's in $\mathbb R^\omega$. Sorry for not responding, i went to sleep.

Comment: sir how can I define infinite sum for finite vector spaces? "The sequence is'nt in R^∞ because..... " please elaborate this line sir. Also one question sir if we take the sum where all but finitely many terms zero, then the sum is defined, eg (1,0,0,...... )+(0,1,0,...... ), but sir here how the sum is finite? Because the tuple is infinite, but yes finitely many terms non zero. Please help sir

Comment: @user639336 You define it the same way as for infinite vector spaces, but you need a topology. You take the sequence of partial sums, and if it converges then you have the infinite sum. Just as you define infinite sums on $\mathbb R$. $\mathbb R^\infty$ is usually considered to be the set of infinite sequences of real numbers where all but finitely many elements of the sequence are $0$. I've seen sometimes that it is considered to be the same as $\mathbb R^\omega$, which doesn't have the finitely many nonzero condition, but that's what I'm used to.

Comment: are you want to say in your comment a set of infinite sequence is in R^∞ if its all elements are zero except finitely many?But the infinite sequence (1,2,3,...... ) is in R^∞ whose all elements are non zero. What is the difference between R^w and R^∞ then?

Comment: @user I'm saying it's not normally considered to be in $\mathbb R^\infty$, unless your book doesn't make the distinction.

Comment: @user By the way, in normal linear algebra with no topology $(1,2,\ldots)$ is not the infinite sum of $e_1+2e_2+\cdots$, even though it's tempting to think of it that way. There is a topology on any vector space that is a countable product over any field that would make that infinite sum make sense, but it still requires topology.

Comment: sir I've copied your comments to quote in which line I've actually problem,"You can also define infinite sums for finite vector spaces, and the same problems arise for infinite ones as for finite ones. That sequence is not in $\mathbb R^\infty$ because all but finitely many need to be zero, but it's in $\mathbb R^\omega$.", please help with this line, why that sequence is'nt in R^∞ but in R^w, is R^∞ and R^w are different?

Comment: @user Yes, and I already explained how they are different.

Comment: sir sorry but I'm unable to understand whats the difference, and specially that line "that sequence is'nt in R^∞ because all but finitely need to be zero", why sir? (1,0,0,........ ) is in R^∞ where all elements are zero except finitely many, but besides (1,2,3,..... ) also in in R^∞, where not all(infact all are non zero) terms are zero. Please help sir.

Comment: it would be huge help if you bear me with my last confusion I stated.

Comment: I'm saying the latter is not in $\mathbb R^\infty$ with the usual definition, but it is in $\Bbb R^\omega$. Some authors use $\mathbb R^\infty$ and $\Bbb R^\omega$ to mean the same thing, but for most $\Bbb R^\infty$ requires all but finitely many components to be zero, whereas $\Bbb R^\omega$ doesn't have that restriction. $\Bbb R^\infty$ has a very nice basis consisting of the standard basis vectors, but a basis for $\Bbb R^\omega$ is unutterably horrible and you can only prove it exists with the axiom of choice.

Comment: sir then what is the basis(standard) for R^∞ then in the usual definition?

Comment: @user It's what you would expect it to be, the standard basis vectors.

Comment: sir you've said in the very beginning that infinite sum is'nt defined in natural sense(binary addition), then how can we write an vector v in R^∞ as a finite linear cobination of those basis vectors? eg (1,-1,1,-1,... ) is in R^∞, then how can we express it as a finite sum of basis vectors? please help sir. I know I'm going wrong somehow, please find it out sir.

Comment: @User The point you're missing is that that vector is not in $\mathbb R^\infty$. It's in $\Bbb R^\omega$, and it can't be written as a finite sum of the same basis vectors. You need additional basis vectors. Uncountably many, and it's impossible to give a complete description.

Comment: sir may be I'm missing something, but thanks a lot for your this effort.Anyways sir can you please suggests some writers of books so that initially I can clear my idea and view about infinite dimensional?

Comment: @user I don't know of any good books, as linear algebra was just something I internalized and remembered forever, never went back to look at a textbook. You might want to ask a second question about this, tagged reference request.

Comment: sir not about linear algebra sir, I mean you said so many things about topology vector space and all, generalized of finite dimension to infinite dimension. I want that type of reference books to know generalized version. If possible please help me.

Comment: @user About to go to sleep. Guessing you're not quite on the opposite side of the world from me, but quite a ways around. Will possibly respond tomorrow.

Comment: sir no problem, you please response tomorrow. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @user I still can only suggest that you ask a separate question about a book. I don't remember where I learned this stuff, and my math books are not accessible so I can't look it up. Someone on the site will definitely know though.

Comment: sir you helped me enough sir, thank you so much. I hope in my posts in future you will do the same

Comment: @user You're welcome.